# How to enable onFailure call back in Kafka Producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, callback, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am writing a kafka producer and below is my class.

```
public class KafkaPublisher {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    KafkaProducer producer;

    public void pushKafkaNotification(String partitionKey, String serializedKafkaNotification, String topic)
    {
        try {
            producer.beginTransaction();
            ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String,String>(topic,partitionKey,serializedKafkaNotification);
            Future<RecordMetadata> result = producer.send(producerRecord);
            producer.commitTransaction();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            producer.abortTransaction();
            log.error("Exception while pushing notification to kafka for user = {}", partitionKey,  e);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I enable onFailure call back in this so that I can know through the logs if something failed ?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution, assuming you didn't need to log parameters to your push method. You should have all the information you need from the RecordMetadata.

```
producer.send(producerRecord, this);
```

```
public class KafkaPublisher implements Callback {

   ... 

   @Override
    public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
        // ... 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how you do it.

```
            producer.send(producerRecord, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                    if(e!=null)
                    {
                        log.error("Callback : Failed to push event to kafka for partition key, notification {] {}", partitionKey, serializedKafkaNotification, e);
                    }
                }
            });
```